# Avoid overlapping compound nodes

Tags: cytoscape.js

We use some [specific layouts](https://github.com/kiali/kiali-ui/blob/master/src/config/Config.ts#L34-L38) to visualize istio's service mesh, and we "Compound nodes" to group nodes of the same service (but different versions).

The problem here is that sometimes one or all of the layouts draws a big compound node that looks like is grouping more nodes than needed.

Look at the next screenshot, it looks like the "reviews" compound node has a lot of nodes, the truth is that the review box only has the top left "v2" and "v1" and the bottom right "v3".

[image: Compound node_1]

I was thinking of a way to workaround this would be:

1. Remove the contents of compound nodes (giving them enough space for later)
2. Layout the remaining nodes
3. Manually fill the compound nodes (e.g. using a manual vertical layout)

I was wondering whether is there a more simple approach, if not I was thinking on wrapping this idea on a Layout which receives the "real layout" upon creation e.g.

```
const coseLayout = cy.layout({name: 'cose', ...});
const compoundNodeFixer = cy.layout({name: 'compoundnodefixer', real_layout: coseLayout});
compoundNodeFixer.run();
```

Update: What we did in the end was to implement something like mentioned above as a new layout. It's not perfect but it works for our use case. [The code is public](https://github.com/kiali/kiali-ui/blob/master/src/components/CytoscapeGraph/Layout/BoxLayout.ts).

Comment: you might want to give `cose-bilkent` layout extension a try. `cose` layout extension is a crappy implementation of CoSE layout algorithm. If configured correctly `cose-bilkent` should not produce overlaps.

Comment: We use cose-bilkent, but is not technically an overlap (I think). The compound node looks like has more nodes than it should.

Comment: I replicated your graph from the image above and then applied the `cose-bilkent` layout, but I could not reproduce anything similar to the image above. Could you provide a demo (JSFiddle or something similar) of the described problem?

Comment: It is considered overlap, because the nodes that are not children of compound node `reviews` and placed on top of it (`ratings`, `mongodb` and etc.) are overlapping with it.

Comment: I'll try to put a demo using "cose-bilkent". The problem is that we use dagre, cose-bilkent and cola for dynamically generated graphs, each layout does a better job on some graphs, but there are layouts on which all the layouts show a output similar to the image.

Answer (score 1):

Achieving this is quite hard if you **need** to use a specific layout, as you may have seen a dozen other unanswered questions about node/label overlapping here on StackOverflow.

However there is still the cytoscape-cola.js layout, it provides the needed spacing and has the cool effect of pushing other nodes away. If you can use it, it may just be the right choice for you:

```js
var cy;

var elements = [{
    data: {
      id: 'M',
      parent: 'B'
    }
  },
  {
    data: {
      id: 'B'
    }
  },
  {
    data: {
      id: 'H',
      parent: 'B'
    }
  },
  {
    data: {
      id: 'F'
    }
  },
  {
    data: {
      id: 'H2'
    }
  },
  {
    data: {
      id: 'T'
    }
  },
  {
    data: {
      id: 'A'
    }
  },
  {
    data: {
      id: 'e2',
      source: 'M',
      target: 'H'
    }
  },
  {
    data: {
      id: 'e3',
      source: 'M',
      target: 'F'
    }
  },
  {
    data: {
      id: 'e4',
      source: 'F',
      target: 'T'
    }
  }
]

$(function() { // on dom ready

  cy = cytoscape({
    container: $('#cy'),
    elements: elements,
    layout: {

      name: 'cola',
      infinite: true,
      fit: false
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#cy {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1em;
  top: 1em;
  bottom: 1em;
  right: 17em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

html {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape@3.2.18/dist/cytoscape.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/webcola/WebCola/cola.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-cola@2.2.3/cytoscape-cola.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Unfortunately, it is **not a core layout** but an extension layout, you may or may not experience performance **enhancement** when using them.

Comment: Cola is pretty quick these days, and the directed feature of Cola may be useful here.